# Error a aplicar evento onmouse over sobre imagen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Hola necesito ayuda para poder aplicar un efecto de esta web:
Cuando pasamos el ratón por encima de una imagen(botella) sale la imagen ampliada a la izquierda, ver:
 [https://www.francisfordcoppolawinery.com/en/our-wines][1]

No puedo realizar el efecto en miweb de cuando se pasa el ratón por encima de una imagen y esta sale en otra sección a al izquierda como en la web anterior.

Tengo este código pero no lo consigo :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-scrict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#id-main {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}

header {
width: 500px;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 500px;
float:left;
}


</style>

</head>

<header></header>

<body>
<img src="img/sparkling.png" width="400px" height="400px" onmouseover="hacer_hover()"">

<script type="text/javascript">

function hacer_hover() 
{
 $("header").css('background-image', 'url(img/sparkling.png)');
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, deberías incluir tu código en un snippet y explicar mejor el caso

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, describe mejor qué quieres lograr. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla y darte una solución. Saludos.

Comment: La he editado espero que sea mas comprensible ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo este código que podría responder tu pregunta, sin embargo si no entiendes algo pónmelo en comentarios y te ayudare a resolver tus dudas

```js
let imgList = document.querySelectorAll('img')
let aside = document.querySelector('.aside')
for(let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++){
  imgList[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
    aside.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.src + ")"
    aside.clientHeight
    aside.classList.add('visible')
  })
  imgList[i].addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    aside.classList.remove('visible')
  })
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.aside {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me hago una buena idea  de como poder realizarlo utilizando flexbox. Espero poder realizarlo en mi web exa en wordpress sin problemas.